# Previous actions remain

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a user input whereby there are 2 inputs cell A1 and cell B1. For actions of cell A1, my code is as follows:

```
If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("A1")
            Case "Hide1"
                Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Hide2"
                Range("A7:A9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End Select
End If
```

For actions of cell A2,my code is as follows:

```
If target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("A2")
            Case "Hide3"
                Range("A11:A13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Hide4"
                Range("A15:A17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End Select
End If
```

How do I make sure that after changing A1, the actions (rows hidden) continue even after I change A2? E.g. I change A1 to "Hide 1", Rows 3-5 gets hidden. Next, I change A2 to "Hide 3", I want Rows 11-13 gets hidden while Rows 3-5 continues to get hidden.

Comment: Can you show the procedure/function name and variables?

Comment: Can we conclude that at any time you want only one set of rows hidden? If not, please do clarify. Also, clarify if it is `B1` (first sentence) or `A2` (code). Also, is this happening in one worksheet? Clarify if not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem. After changing A1 to "Hide1" and A2 to "Hide3" rows 3-5 remain hidden. Look perhaps on another part of the code.
I can imagine perhaps your code is in SelectionChange event, while it should be in Change event:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("A1")
            Case "Hide1"
                Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Hide2"
                Range("A7:A9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Range("A7:A9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    Else
        If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
            Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("A2")
                Case "Hide3"
                    Range("A11:A13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case "Hide4"
                    Range("A15:A17").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Case Else
                    Range("A11:A13").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Range("A15:A17").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Select Case Sheets("Input").Range("A1")
    Case "Hide1"
        Application.EnableEvents=False
        Range("A3:A5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Application.EnableEvents=True
    Case "Hide2"
        Application.EnableEvents==False
        Range("A7:A9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Application.EnableEvents=True
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet Change: Hide Rows

- This is happening in one worksheet. The code needs to be copied to its module, e.g. `Sheet1`, `Input`...etc.
- This will monitor changes in cells `A1` (values "Hide1" and "Hide2") and `A2` (values "Hide3" and "Hide4") and at any time, only one of all four 'row sets' will get hidden.
- If both cells were changed, only the first cell's rows will get hidden (see `Exit For`).
- Although the range (`urg`) represents entire rows, `.EntireRow` is still necessary when hiding.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim sAddresses As Variant: sAddresses = VBA.Array("A1", "A2")
    Dim uVals As Variant: uVals = VBA.Array("Hide1", "Hide2", "Hide3", "Hide4")
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = Range("3:5,7:9,11:13,15:17")
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(sAddresses)
        Set sCell = Range(sAddresses(n))
        Set iCell = Intersect(sCell, Target)
        If Not iCell Is Nothing Then
            urg.EntireRow.Hidden = False ' unhide all 'row sets'
            Select Case LCase(iCell.Value)
            Case LCase(uVals(n * 2))
                urg.Areas(n * 2 + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case LCase(uVals(n * 2 + 1))
                urg.Areas(n * 2 + 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End Select
            ' If both cells are changed, only the first cell's rows get hidden
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n

End Sub
```